# Overriding TextBox height property default value

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom control deriving from `TextBox`. I am trying to override the default value of it's `Height` property, but I keep getting an error that the types don't match.

> Metadata override and base metadata must be of the same type or derived type.

on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx) it states that `Height` property is of type `System.Double`.

I have tried the following:

1) converting to double

```
HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SuggestionTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(Convert.ToDouble(200)));
```

and

```
HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SuggestionTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata((double)200));
```

2) Tried to figure out the the default value by

```
HeightProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue
```

Which returns [Double.NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx)

**EDIT:** I'm doing this in the static constructor of the control as shown in the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209.aspx)

Any Idea how I can override it's default values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with the Type of Default value but with the Type of `PropertyMetaData`,
Instead of `UIPropertyMetadata` you will have to use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` as this is what `HeightProperty` metadata type is.

```
HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SuggestionTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Convert.ToDouble(200)));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'll take it as a sign that it's enough work for one day ... :P

Comment: yah..specially for sunday ;)